# How to print images to PDF with the Xportability plugin

Tags: javascript, css, pdf

I'm using [Xportability plugin](https://github.com/Xportability/css-to-pdf) to create a pdf with an image, but so far i get the text just fine but images always get that default icon when the page can't find the actual image, other times i get this error on the console:

```
Error: Permission denied to access property 0   xepOnline.jqPlugin.js
```

and creates a duplicate of the elements that were supposed to be printed.
I looked at the brief documentation on the site and with `{embedLocalImages : 'true'}` (also i tried `{embedLocalImages : true}`)it prints images on the pdf document, but no result.

```
<a class="btn btn-success btn-xs" onclick="return xepOnline.Formatter.Format('reporte',{embedLocalImages : 'true'});">
        Descargar reporte      
    </a>
```

Anyone with experience with this plugin can help? what's wrong? Did i missed something?

**Update:**
i managed to modify the script the images are now showing but it takes some time to do function correctly, still get the error message and the elements to be printed get duplicated, not sure why but later i get the pdf correctly.

Comment: Are you running via http or localhost?

Comment: all is localhost

Comment: Are the inline image in img tag or background or other, I wrote the code for the plug in and it attempts to convert image local to based and send as the remote server would not have access to your local host images. It will only work for inline img. You can send help request to me through the site.

Comment: all images are inline images